# How do I create a GLKViewController that starts in a paused state?

Tags: ios, glkit

I create a `GLKViewController` like this:

```
// Create a GLK View Controller to handle animation timings
_glkVC = [[GLKViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
_glkVC.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;
_glkVC.view = self.glkView;
_glkVC.delegate = self;
_glkVC.paused = YES;
NSLog(@"initial state: %@", _glkVC.paused ? @"paused" : @"running");
```

but it immediately starts calling the delegate update method and the output from the `NSLog` above is: `initial state: running`

I am managing my view updates with `setNeedsDisplay` but I want the `GLKViewController` to handle animations from time to time so I want to unpause it only when needed. Is there a way to start the controller in a paused state?

Comment: I'd like to open this question up again. The FPS workaround is ok, but surely there's a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of any answers I'm using this work-around:

I set `.preferredFramesPerSecond = 1` initially and then in the update method I check `if(preferredFramesPerSecond == 1)` and set `.paused = YES` (and also set my real desired value for `preferredFramesPerSecond`). I can then allow the rest of the update method to run once after initialisation, or return immediately if I don't want it to run yet.

I then trigger redraws manually as needed with `setNeedsDisplay` and unpause it when I need it to animate.

If anyone has a better solution please answer as usual.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried pausing in the viewDidAppear method instead of the viewDidLoad method?  It should look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];    
    // self.paused automatically set to NO in super's implementation
    self.paused = YES;
}
```

Boom, done! If this works then you save an "if" check thousands of times a minute just to pause on launch!

Comment: This doesn't work. The draw method is fired a couple of times before `viewDidAppear` is hit.

Answer (score 2):

The viewDidAppear method works for me, but not optimally. A few frames of visible animation occur before the pause takes effect. Using viewWillAppear worked much better:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated
{
  [ super viewDidAppear: animated ];
  self.paused = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overriding `resumeOnDidBecomeActive` to return **NO**?  This should keep the animation paused on any activation, including the first.